# Command Line: Using a for loop to create directories with increasing names

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, dos, mkdir

I am trying to write a batch file that does the following:

1. Prompt user for the directory to create the new folder *newest*
2. Prompt user for an integer *limit*
3. Create directory *newest*
4. CD *newest*
5. FOR loop for *limit* iterations

   - Create directory "Month " + *iteration*

For example:

*newest* = Reports

*limit* = 12

I should end up with:

\Reports\Month 1

\Reports\Month 2

\Reports\Month 3

...

\Reports\Month 12

This is my code so far:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%limit%) DO (
set "month_counter=Month %%i"
echo %month_counter%
MD %month_counter%
)
endlocal
```

If I set *limit* = 12, I get 12 error messages stating:

```
Echo is off.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%limit%) DO (
 MD "Month %%i"
)
```

You have the standard `delayed expansion` problem - hundreds of articles on SO about this.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

So - you *could* use

```
set "month_counter=Month %%i"
CALL echo %%month_counter%%
```

If you really, really want to - or one of the other techniques, but it's far easier to simply make the directory from your constant data + the iteration counter in `%%i` as shown.

Comment: That help out so much. I don't know why I was over-complicating it. I was not are of the difference between parsed code before and after execution.